# Files uploaded to Github main branch not showing up on my Github page

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm just learning how to code and I've come across an issue. I'm using github pages to host my personal site and some of the files I upload don't appear on the page. I have an images folder on my main branch where I have 3 images [(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy0qb.png). However when I go to my site and look at the sources dev tools tab, I only see 2 of my images in the images file [(picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP4PB.png). I've tried re uploading the image and I don't see anything wrong with my html.  Does anyone know why the files are not showing up?

Here is my Github Repository: https://github.com/sanfranciscoave/sanfranciscoave.github.io

Here is my github Page:
https://sanfranciscoave.github.io/

Comment: How are you "uploading" these files?  Can you add the Git commands you used to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github pages files are case sensitive.

Your github file name is AlanTuringTributePage.PNG with Page caps and your page source has images/AlanTuringTributepage.PNG class="img-fluid" id="myWork1"> with a small p

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem. Cant believe I didn't catch that.